# Failure to recode levels of a factor with dplyr mutate() and recode_factor

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr, recode

I have:

```
library(tidyverse)
mood <- 
  tibble(cond = factor(c('pl', 'nu', 'un')), rating = 1:3)
```

I would like to mutate mood into:

```
moodWish <-
  tibble(cond = factor(c('P', 'N', 'U')), rating = 1:3)
```

I tried:

```
mood1 <- mood %>%
  mutate(cond = recode_factor(cond,
                              'P' = 'pl',
                              'N' = 'nu',
                              'U' = 'un'))
```

I know that recode_factor is doing something, because it changes the **order** of the levels of cond but not the levels.

Comment: Try `mood %>% mutate(cond = recode(cond, 'pl' = "P", 'nu' = 'N', 'un' = 'U'))`

Answer (score 1):

"When named, the argument names should be the current values to be replaced, and the argument values should be the new (replacement) values."

```
> mood1 <- mood %>%
    mutate(cond = recode_factor(cond,
                                'pl' = 'P',
                                'nu' = 'N',
                                'un' = 'U'))

> mood1
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  cond  rating
  <fct>  <int>
1 P          1
2 N          2
3 U          3
```

Comment: This is counter-intuitive in light of how mutate works. It never occurred to me to RTFM, so confident I was that the analogy must hold.